# How to normalize sales distribution percentage across multiple agents using data present in excel?

Tags: excel

I am a part of a company that sells a particular product. We have around 5000 agents who are responsible for all the sales in the area. Each agent is given a fixed number of units to sell, and he reports back the number of units solds at EOD. Currently, to assess the performance of all the agents, we simply calculate the percentage of units sold by the agent, and the agent with higher percentage of units sold is considered to be a better salesman.

[image]

But as the number of units sold is directly linked to the revenue brought to the company, the agent A should be given some **extra** **weightage** while calculating the ranking/percent values. In the current scenrio, even after making the maximum sales, he is currently ranked last just because he was given the maximum number of units to be sold.
I tried normalizing the *units allotted* column, but that didnt help much.

What can be done here to give a true picture regarding the agent's performance ? . Any help in this regard is appreciated. Currently I am using Excel to maintain this data, but I can switch to any other tool if required.

Comment: Can you just simply clarify who would be best agent from your given data? Agent `B`? as he sales highest unit. Or agent `C` as he sales highest percentage?

Comment: @Harun24HR To arrive at the best agent figure, I want to give some weightage to agents who have sold more number of units. if we simply take percentage as a parameter to determine effectiveness of the agent, it will not show us the true picture. In the above scenario, if each agent was given some extra points based on the number of units sold, then percentage calculation or any other mathematical formula would have resulted in better results

Comment: General formula for ranking on 2 criteria would be `=RANK(D2,$D$2:$D$5)+SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$D$5=$D2),--(C2<$C$2:$C$5))` assuming  Column D and Column C as criteria columns. But your situation is going to give same results based on your logic. If you take $5 as profit per unit and make a ranking table as per units sold it will give same ranking order. Further you may refer what situation gives different results <https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4799-excel-rank-on-two-columns.html>

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to calculate a composite rank that is calculated from the Agents rank in the % of units sold and total units sold. I have calculated composite rank in two ways. First from the absolute values of % of units sold and units sold. Second from Agents relative rank in % of units sold and units sold. Assuming Agents Names in in the range `B2:B5` ,% units sold in range `C2:C5`, units sold in the range `D2:D5`. 
The formulas used are Array Formula, so you must press CTRL SHIFT ENTER rather than ENTER when you first enter the formula and whenever you edit it later. If you do this correctly, Excel will display the formulas enclosed in curly braces { }.

•   Formula for relative rank based on % units sold to be CSE entered    in range `E2`

```
 =RANK($C2,$C$2:$C$5)
```

•   Formula for relative rank based on units sold to be CSE entered in range `F2`

```
 =RANK($D2,$D$2:$D$5)
```

•  Formula for composite score based on % units sold and units sold to be CSE entered in range `G2`

```
 =(C2/MAX(ABS($C$2:$C$5)))+(D2/(10^(MAX(LEN(C$2:C$5)+1))))+((ROW()/(10^MAX(LEN($D$2:$D$5)+1))))
```

•  Formula for relative rank based as per first approach on absolute    values of % of units sold and units sold to be CSE entered in range    `H2`

```
 =RANK(G2,$G$2:$G$5,0)+COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2)-1
```

•  Formula for composite score based on Agents relative rank in % of units sold and units    sold.to be CSE entered in range `I2`

```
 =(E2/MAX(ABS($E$2:$E$5)))+(F2/(10^(MAX(LEN(E$2:E$5)+1))))+((ROW()/(10^MAX(LEN($F$2:$F$5)+1))))
```

•  Formula for relative rank based as per first approach on absolute    values of % of units sold and units sold to be CSE entered in range    `J2`

```
 =RANK(I2,$I$2:$I$5,0)+COUNTIF($I$2:I2,I2)-1
```

We get different rankings as per snapshot given below. Sample data may not be fully representative of the whole population. So these approaches may please be tried on actual data for optimal decision. Please also see whether sorting base data makes results different because `Rank Function` is preferred with sorted data. Further reference is [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723)

[image: rank on 2 bases]

Working copy of exercise file is uploaded to drop box [soq_54729849](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwj68rsalue4jrx/soq_54729849.xlsx?dl=0)